# Add validates_uniqueness_of error to another attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a validator in a class like the following

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, {message: 'this is not a unique email :('}
```

What I would like is for this error to add a custom attribute to the errors object, like

```
{errors: {already_invited: true}}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Shouldn't you just change the name of the error message and say "This email already received an invitation"?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, {message: 'this is not a unique email :('}
validate :previous_invite

def previous_invite
  #if already_invited is an attribute of the model then use
  # errors.add(:already_invited, "true") otherwise add it to base
  errors.add(:base, "already invited") if errors.added?(:email,'this is not a unique email :(') 
end
```

You should not just add arbitrary keys to the `errors` but you can if you'd really like it is just considered poor form according to the docs:

> attribute should be set to :base if the error is not directly associated with a single attribute.

Also messages will be treated as Strings not booleans. so it would not be `already_invited: true` but rather `already_invited: "true"`